# Open Source Security Dashboard?

Tags: mod-security, selinux

I'm looking for an open source security dashboard that gives a basic overview of security warnings. Google has pointed me in a few directions but nothing promising. I need something to deal w/ selinux alerts, mod_security violations and hopefully have an api that can send/create new alerts to display (i think i might be asking too much, sadly). A few have suggested custom graphs in kibana but would be nice to hear other peoples thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Splunk?

Very easy to set up, with apps available for *nix platforms and mod_security ready.

Splunk isn't open source, but free to use for up to 500mb of data per day - you can send data via regular syslog, or using their universal forwarder. Their dashboards and charting capabilities are fantastic and easy to use.

You can set up alerts to send emails, trigger actions, run scripts, etc.

Comment: Splunk is very good, but free is not open-source.  The 500MB/day free limit is a real problem, especially for security dashboard solutions where you want lots of events from lots of different sources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specifically say SIEM solutions or event correlation, so I'll take a shot and suggest looking at https://www.icinga.org/.

For monitoring log files, there's articles out there on the subject: http://code.google.com/p/logwarn/ or more descriptive: http://linuxdrops.com/how-to-monitor-log-files-using-nagios-or-icinga/

These kinds of solutions will notify you of log conditions like "too many errors in SELinux logs", but they're not as intelligent as an SIEM which can make decisions like "if there's a problem ticket open, don't alert on the router login, unless there's an authentication on the mcguffin device or exception in the critical outage table"

Also, something I've not checked out which I would like to is Opsview http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsview

Commercial solutions in this area are a lot more powerful, but they're very expensive.